# Center text between floating paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I know that "how to center stuff" questions are kinda annoying and boring, but anyway ...

I'm trying to get one word ("Impressum") to appear perfectly centered in the footer of my wordpress page by putting something like this in the footer.php:

```
<p style="float:left"><a href="http://fachschaft-intermedia.de/impressum/" title="Impressum">Impressum</a></p>
```

The problem is, on the left side of the same line is the copyright notice (floated to the left), on the right side is the theme author credit (floated to the right). I've tried different things to get the word centered (in relation to the width of the page!), but the floating to the left that I need to get my word in the same line as the other stuff screws with the position ...

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GinSan/2t7e3zeq/
Note that most of this is dynamically generated by the theme and I don't want to touch it. Please try to help me by only altering line 3 (i.e. without rebuilding the whole footer ...). Also, though I used a fixed width of 1100px for testing purposes, it should be responsive and stay in the center regardless of the width of the page (down to 640px).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your "impress" paragraph at the and of the footer and replace `float:left` with `text-align:center`. Here is [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2t7e3zeq/1/)

Comment: That works, thanks! Didn't think of that since it wouldn't work once the width got to small, but since the paragraphs are split to three lines below 640px anyway ... :D
Also, until your answer I didn't realise that "Impressum" wasn't actually a word in English °ω° (It is in German though)

Answer (score 0):

in the jsfiddle this run, in your page you might position: relative for the first div

```
<div style="width:1100px">
    <p style="float:left">© 2014 foo</p>
    <p   style="position: absolute;text-align: center;width: 100%;"><a href="http://fachschaft-intermedia.de/impressum/" title="Impressum">Impressum</a></p>
    <p style="float:right;text-align:right">Powered by Theme</a></p>
</div>
```